# Lenovo K3 note (-) icon

Tags: android, mobile

Lenovo K3 note (-) icon
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdw8h.jpg)

Hi, Hypen like icon appears on the top of the screen. Why am I getting it? What does it mean? Pl. Help.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com).

Answer (score 1):

offtopic, stackoverflow is about programming...

btw. it means you have set "alarms only" mode, other notifications and sounds (including ringtones) are muted. its Android icon, present on various devices, not only your Lenovo